# LinqToSql - Is there an alternative to chaining .Replace() to remove characters from database column on comparison?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a where, where a database value starts with a user input string, but I need to remove spaces and special characters from both sides of the string.

Any of these:
`O B`
`OB`
`O'B`
Should match any of these:
`O'Brian`
`O Brian`
`OBrian`

Normally I would use regex to take out all non-alphanumeric characters, but LinqtoSql doesn't seem to be able to use regex. I did find SqlMethods.Like for pattern matching, but I cant use it to remove characters from both sides as far as I can tell.

The only way I've been able to figure out how to do this is with something like this:
`x.LastName.Replace("", String.Empty).Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace("[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty.StartsWith(lastname.Replace("", String.Empty).Replace("'", String.Empty).Replace("[", String.Empty).Replace("]", String.Empty) )`

Which works, but having a .Replace for every single non alpha character is very lengthy and difficult to read. Is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a version of replace that accepts a Array? If not, could you write one? | LINQ to SQL should still be limited to what SQL can actually do. Wich is less then what LINQ can do. | Personally I never was a friend of hiding that you are working with SQL behind LinqToSql. It really just confuses you over what is possible.

Comment: I made a function that you could pass in an array of Chars, but then it said LinqToSql couldn't translate it.

I'm not a fan of LinqToSql either but I don't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: What you have here is basically a bunch of calls to replace(string, string) in a loop. Make a string, string class and you can hand in an array and loop over it. Pretty sure LINQ is only resolved when you start ittearting over it.